# I want to transfer chrome and IE files

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

How can I manually transfer (without third party software), all the original files in my Google chrome, Firefox and IE9 (I want them to feel exactly the same): History, Bookmarks, Cookies, Passwords etc. If I were to install a new Windows installation, and remove the old one? I'm currently on Windows 7.

Will they work properly and stable on the new OS installation (Win7)?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Firefox are relatively easy about this, a matter of copying folders...IE handles things slightly different it seems, more Info behind the links:

• [Chrome](http://saifulaiub123.hubpages.com/hub/How-To-Backup-Or-Recover-Google-Chrome-Bookmarks-and-Profile)

• [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/back-and-restore-information-firefox-profiles)

• [Internet Explorer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_7/is-there-a-way-to-backup-ie10s-settings-and/72e444b9-b3cd-48da-b90a-0be7a2621cc3)

Comment: please do your best to describe in your answer the relevant steps instead of placing links for the answer - if the links ever get broken, so does your whole answer.

Comment: yep. i'll get back to it soon

Answer (score 0):

for ie9:

If you use Internet Explorer on more than one computer, you can export your favorites from one computer and import them to another.

To export favorites:

Open Internet Explorer.

Click the Favorites button.

Click the arrow next to the Add to favorites button, and then select Import and export.

In the Import/Export Settings dialog box, select Export to a file, and then click Next.

Select Favorites (and any other settings) you'd like to export, and then click Next.

Select the folders of favorites that you want to export, and then click Next.

By default, Internet Explorer creates a file called bookmark.htm in your Documents folder. If you want to store the exported favorites to a place other than Documents (like a disc or a flash drive), click Browse, and then select a different drive. Click Save.

Click Finish.